# Inversion of the function $ \sqrt x \ln x $

Tags: logarithms, inverse, closed-form, inverse-function

Is there an **exact** (not asymptotic) inversion of the function  $ \sqrt x \ln x $ or can we only obtain this inverse in terms of a power series?

Comment: You can do such things with the Lambert W-function, otherwise no. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 4):

Let $x = e^z$. We have:
$$
y = \sqrt{x} \ln{x} = \exp\left(\frac{z}{2}\right) z
$$

Thus:
$$
\frac{y}{2} =  \frac{z}{2} \exp\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)
$$

Using the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we have:
$$
\frac{z}{2} = W\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)
$$

Put $x$ back to get:
$$
x = \exp\left(2 W\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)
$$

This is as close to a closed form as you can get. The function cannot be expressed in elementary functions.